# How would you build a mobile-style Shift key in WPF?

Tags: wpf, button, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a virtual keyboard for a touch screen based application in WPF. However, because it is touch screen based, I will have to make it like a mobile or tablet styled keyboard.

And here's where I'm stuck. Most computer keyboards have a `Shift` key and a `Shift Lock` key, where the former only capitalizes letters when pressed together with a key while the other effectively toggles the capitalization mode. On mobile devices, however, these two functionalities are often combined into a single key that can be pressed once to capitalize the next key or pressed twice to toggle the capitalization mode.

How would you accomplish this with WPF? I know there exists a `ToggleButton` control but it can only cycle between two states as opposed to the required three states:

`Shift Lock` key states (regular `ToggleButton`):

1. Don't capitalize anything
2. Capitalize all subsequent inputs

`Mobile Shift Lock` key states:

1. Don't capitalize anything
2. Capitalize only the next input (and return to 1)
3. Capitalize all subsequent inputs

Comment: How is this supposed to interact with the usual keyboard behaviour. EG what happens if the user has caps lock on from their keyboard? Or is this maybe supposed to set that?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention this was supposed to be a touch screen based application so it would be completely independent from potential keyboard inputs, I'll edit my question.

Comment: `ToggleButton` can have three states if you set `IsThreeState` property to `true`

Comment: @Mitya oh damn you're right, I guess I should've read the docs better. So what if I hypothetically wanted to add yet another state on top of that?

Comment: @JansthcirlU I guess you have to implement your custom control then.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: You can handle textinput before and after it has an effect. So you could upshift based on a flag. Set that flag to true when they hit the button. Unset it after the first input. Add another flag to keep the value. I think you'd need to preview touchdown and touch up events and check the time between them to check for a long press. There might be a long touch input though, I've not done much touch handling with wpf.